# How to delete searched row from jtable and sql database based on searched value

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, swing

I've created a sql database with a table called users. It holds the user_id, user_name and email. I've created a form that allows the user to search for any record and displays the filtered record on a `JTable`.

I want to delete the row the search result filters based on the searched value meaning the user can search either the user_id, user_name or email.

> users {user_id, user_name, email}

This is what I have

```
private void deleteSelectedRows(){
   try {
        String sql = "DELETE from user where ? = ?";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, searchTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(2, searchTxt.getText());
       ((DefaultTableModel)userTable.getModel()).removeRow(userTable.getSelectedRow());

      pst.execute();

    } catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

`searchTxt` is the text field.
This code deletes all the rows in my table.

If I change it to `DELETE from user where user_id = ?`, it only deletes the row when it is searched by user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

users {user_id, user_name, email}

```
   private void deleteSelectedRows(){
       try {
          String sql = "DELETE from user where ? = ?";
          pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          pst.setString(1, searchTxt.getText());
          pst.setString(2, searchTxt.getText());

         ((DefaultTableModel) userTable.getModel()).removeRow(userTable.getSelectedRow());

         pst.execute();
    } catch (Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
 }
```

With that code you're always producing a complete deletion of the table because you always obtain a `TRUE` in your WHERE clause

If `searchTxt.getText()` is "hello", the prepared statement will be

```
   DELETE from user where hello = hello
```

Which is equivalent to

```
   DELETE from user where true
```

Or

```
   DELETE from user
```

You just have to differentiate between `searchTxt` and `columnName`

```
   private void deleteSelectedRows(){
       try {
          String sql = "DELETE from user where ? = ?";
          pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          pst.setString(1, columnName);
          pst.setString(2, searchTxt.getText());

         ((DefaultTableModel) userTable.getModel()).removeRow(userTable.getSelectedRow());

         pst.execute();
    } catch (Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a great explanation. Do I use multiple column names since multiple columns are involved?

Comment: @TLin  But you have to use different searchTxt also, one per columnName and have to contruct the query dinamically if not all the fields are used on the search. Be so kind to mark the answer as accepted if it has been useful.

Comment: I used a Combo Box and fixed the search to be based on the values selected from the Combo Box and it worked! Thank you and your approval is on the way!